# how to reference data from same point of time over last 30 days in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of 1 minute data in Excel of last 30 days.
I am trying to compare today's value at 05:45:00 with average of last 30 days value at same time (05:45:00).
Completely stuck.

Can anyone help: Dataset looks like this:

```
Time    Value
05:30:00    11.00
05:31:00    6.00
05:32:00    20.00
05:33:00    50.00
05:34:00    69.00
05:35:00    31.00
05:36:00    90.00
05:37:00    56.00
05:38:00    26.00
05:39:00    24.00
05:40:00    22.00
05:41:00    71.00
05:42:00    80.00
05:43:00    85.00
05:44:00    41.00
**05:45:00  44.00**
05:46:00    28.00
05:47:00    43.00
```

I did try to convert days in to minutes by doing

`=(last day - first day)*1440`

after that I am completely stuck what needs to be done. Not very proficient with Excel.

Comment: Have you tried averageif() ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware how datetime works in Excel?
It is based on the value "1" being equal to one day.

So, the hour-value "05:30" equals "=5.5/24" as you can see from this screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot with datetimes]

So, If you want to add 30 days to a timestamp, just add the value 30.